# Selenium can't send keys in found element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have an element with this outerHtml -

```
<input class="inp-text ps-component ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 200, 'blur': 0 } }" required="required" maxlength="100" ng-model="model.name"/>
```

I had tried -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input"));
```

can find this element, but when I try to do

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")).sendKeys("something");
```

java tell me that the `element is not visible` exception

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")).click();
```

don't work too.

How to send some keys in this input element?

I found a part of solution. click() work if use it:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input"))
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", input);
```

But I still don't understand how to send keys in it.

Comment: Check my answer. It contains JavascripExecutor `sendKeys()`.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 2):

Try using explicit wait with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to make sure the element is visible before interacting with it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input")));
element.sendKeys("something");
```

Comment: I said findElement() works. So it's not invisible. I don't need to wait it.

Comment: @BerasMark If `findElement()` works it means the element *exist* in the DOM. It doesn't mean it *visible*. You can even see it in the error message "java tell me that the element is not visible."

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue where the elements were not visible to the `WebDriver`. Instead a `JavascriptExecutor` was able to help me out. Here are some simple applications:

`sendKeys()` with JavascriptExecutor:

```
// Cast driver to JavascriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("element = document.getElementsByTagName('input');");
jse.executeScript("element(0).value='" + yourInputString + "';");
```

`click()` with JavascriptExecutor:

```
// Cast driver to JavascriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("javascript:submitForm()");
```

Comment: May be u meant element[0] instead element(0)? Anyway, it still don't send keys in my input form

Comment: It's `element(0)`. Note that you are fetching all elements tagged `input` (`getElements...`). You need to make sure your input field is the first of those elements or that you are sending input to a correct element in the list.

Comment: I think that Selenium tries to simulate actual keyboard and mouse clicks. If you care about this (_e.g._ if you're using Selenium to test that a webpage is usable by an actual user) then using JavaScript might be short-circuiting what you're trying to test.  However, I don't care about this in my case, and your solution worked for me. :)   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to locate using tag name i.e. `<input>`
this tag can be multiple in same page in this case .

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input"));
```

will not show any error .
 just make your locator more specific and then try  e.g.-

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.ps-component.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched.ng-pristine.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required")).sendKeys("your_Value");
```

or you can loacate you element according to uniqueness in your page.

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value=\"" + myText + "\";", input);
```